# Android curl half page, both side

Tags: android, curl, flip

I am looking for android library which has pages like Aphid library (means half page turn with front and back) but with curl effect.

You can find Aphid library [here](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

Comment: I have already tried this but my requirement is to have single page instead of two pages, and effect should be like folding the single page with curl effect

Comment: @Asheesh, I have something similar to your requirements: [Link](http://mbsmin.tistory.com/category/android?page=1)

Comment: I have already tried these library, I need flipping of page with curling effect.

Comment: Yes, this will provide that effect only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [Library](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView), also you can try this code of [Page curl effect in Android](http://www.hasmukhbhadani.com/2013/07/page-curl-effect-in-android.html), also here's a [source code](http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1690539/) that may hel you out :)

Hope it works!

Comment: I have already tried these library, I need flipping of page with curling effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native FlipView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html or go GL https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Comment: I have already tried these library, I need flipping of page with curling effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Page Curl for Android](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl)

The android-page-curl is a 2D View which simulates a page curl effect. Without OpenGL, only the android canvas has been used, so that it can be used in any version of Android!

Comment: I have already tried these library, I need flipping of page with curling effect.